# Find the average of an array with objects (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, function, object, methods

I am writing some code that takes an array of shapes and finds the average of the array. The concept itself is quite simple but I am having problems. What I did to try to implement the method to find the average is that I used a for loop to add all the values of the array together and then I divided the sum with the number of items in the array. Although I understand how to do this clearly, for some reason I am getting problems. For the equation where I continuously add the previous sum to the new sum, the array gives me an error that says "Expression expected". I am not sure on what that means so I used the IDE fix and it created a new private object for me at the top of the class. Then it gives me another error, it says "Array type expected, java.lang.Object" I was unsure so I decided to import the lang.Object into the file but the error remained the same. How can I fix this?

This is my code below:

```
public class Main{

    private GeometricShape[] shapes;
    private Object GeometricShape;


    public static void main(String[] args){


    }

    public void GeometricShapeTester(){
        shapes = new GeometricShape[20];
        Random rand = new Random();

    public double findAverage(){
        double total = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < shapes.length; i++){
            total = total + GeometricShape[i];
        }
        double average = total / shapes.length;

        return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: we don't know how geometric shape looks like.

Comment: `private Object GeometricShape;` What is this supposed to do?

Comment: As @Goion said we have to see `GeometricShape` implementation. BTW how do you expect adding a `double` value with a `GeometricShape` value and assign it to another `double` work?

Comment: `total = total + GeometricShape[i];` maybe you need to change it to `total = total + shapes[i];`

Comment: @sanjeevRm this I have tried, but when I type it, it gives me an error saying "operator '+' cannot be applied to 'double' ,'GeometricShape'"

Comment: @sanjeevRm is on the right track but your question is unanswerable without the source of `GeometricShape` if it's your code, or a link to its Javadoc if it isn't. Presumably you want to sum some *attribute* of `GeometricShape`, but you haven't confided in us what it is. And please format your code correctly.

Comment: You can't add an Object to a double and have it make sense.

Comment: @NomadMaker why is that so? (I'm a beginner so I don't quite understand why it is not possible)

Comment: @ShawnHawkins What sense *should* it make? What value should be added to the `double`? Please clarify your question as requested by everybody here, by posting the missing code.

Comment: A double holds a floating point number. An object is something very different, like a String, or an Employee, or a Book. What is the value of 2.5 + "War and Peace"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for error `Array type expected, java.lang.Object"` is belowline

```
`total = total + GeometricShape[i];
```

maybe you need to change it to

```
total = total + shapes[i];
```

Comment: this I have tried, but when I type it, it gives me an error saying "operator '+' cannot be applied to 'double' ,'GeometricShape'"

Comment: @ShawnHawkins you should probably add parameters of GerometricShape not the object itself